# How to filter and access ManyToMany fields in a Django QuerySet?

Tags: django, python-3.x, many-to-many, django-queryset

Suppose I have the following models with a ManyToMany relationship:

```
class City(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Course(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cities = models.ManyToManyField(City)
```

Now I want to filter for the courses with a given name in a given city:

```
courses = Course.objects.filter(name='Course1', cities__name='City1')
```

Is it possible to access the `City` fields through the `courses` QuerySet? In this example, would it be possible to get `'City1'` from `courses` only?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`prefetch_related`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-related) with a [Prefetch object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#prefetch-objects) to do this.

```
city1 = City.objects.filter(name='City1')
courses = Course.objects.filter(name='Course1', cities__name='City1').prefetch_related(
    Prefetch('cities', queryset=city1)
)
```